# Не удается забрать сессию при работе с форумом phpBB

Tags: phpbb, php

Есть форум на этом движке. Все нормально установилось. Хочу написать страничку, которая будет брать оттуда информацию о пользователе (его сессию) и использовать. Т.е. если на форуме авторизовался, то и на той страничке тоже, и наоборот, но мои попытки забрать сессию завершились неудачей.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно посмотреть какие ключи использует сессия в данном движке, и использовать её на других страницах